# calculate no of days between mysql timestamp and php current date

Tags: php, mysql

I am getting php date with date("Y-m-d") as 2014-03-14 and

mysql timestamp is 2014-03-02 03:2:23

I want to get as 12 days.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DATEDIFF('2014-03-14',DATE(mysql_timestamp))
```